# Android Design Dependency

Tags: android, android-layout

I dynamically created LinearLayout and set background drawable in that layout

When that Layout idle it appears good

[image: When idle]

the problem is when i click username edittext the layout has splitted

[image: When username clicked]

when i click the password edittext that layout collapsed

[image: When password clicked]

If it can be solved please give some suggestion

Drawable : button_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/> 
   <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

Note:

Username and password is separate LinearLayout

Login and SignUp button is separate LinearLayout;

Dynamic Linear Layout code

```
LinearLayout mainlayout = new LinearLayout(con);
        mainlayout.setOrientation(1);
        mainlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            TextView tv = new TextView(con);
            EditText et = new EditText(con);
            tv.setText(data.get(i));
            tv.setHeight(50);
            tv.setPadding(22, 0, 0, 0);
            tv.setTextColor(0xff000000);
            mainlayout.addView(tv);
            et.setHint("Tap To Type");
            mainlayout.addView(et);
        }
```

Comment: It will be difficult for you to get some help if you do not include the code that dynamically creates the `LinearLayout` and set its drawable background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You have applied background to username and password layout. In the same way try to apply background for `editText` also. If you don't then `editText` will use its default properties and collapse with its parent when focused. Hope it helps.

Edit: Myself I ran code. Its working fine.

```
LinearLayout mainlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainlayout.setOrientation(1);
    mainlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_xml));

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        tv.setText(""+i);
        tv.setHeight(50);
        tv.setPadding(22, 0, 0, 0);
        tv.setTextColor(0xff000000);
        mainlayout.addView(tv);
        et.setHint("Tap To Type");
        et.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));
        mainlayout.addView(et);
    }

    addContentView(mainlayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
```

drawable for editText

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>
```

Comment: Here is My  dynamic linearlayout code

LinearLayout mainlayout = new LinearLayout(con);
  mainlayout.setOrientation(1);
  mainlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
  
  for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
   TextView tv = new TextView(con);
   EditText et = new EditText(con);
   tv.setText(data.get(i));
   tv.setHeight(50);
   tv.setPadding(22, 0, 0, 0);
   tv.setTextColor(0xff000000);
   mainlayout.addView(tv);
   et.setHint("Tap To Type");
   mainlayout.addView(et);
  }

Comment: For that editText et, set a background as u set for mainLayout

Comment: LinearLayout mainlayout = new LinearLayout(con);
        mainlayout.setOrientation(1);
        mainlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            TextView tv = new TextView(con);
            EditText et = new EditText(con);
            tv.setText(data.get(i));
            tv.setHeight(50);
            tv.setPadding(22, 0, 0, 0);
            tv.setTextColor(0xff000000);
            mainlayout.addView(tv);
            et.setHint("Tap To Type");
            et.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            mainlayout.addView(et);
        }

Comment: are u setting same drawable to editText which u used for mainLayout?

Comment: try to use different, simple drawable without any corners(use square) because as ur parent view has got cornered background, again cornered background for children's inside may alter look

Comment: I setting different drawable in editTextView but still having the same problem

Comment: I hv also added screenshot of your code in action. Its working fine. Check once again for yourself. May its not taking proper resource. Try to clean project